# Unable to convert indexed array to associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array

The array `$digit` now has data in this form :

```
'numbers' => 
  array (
    0 => '1,2,3',
  )
```

But I need that array in the below shown form:

```
'numbers' => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
  ),
```

How to achieve this?

I tried the below things. But all those are returning data in same form as I currently have .Any help is appreciated.

**Method 1:**

```
$newDigitsArray=[];
$i=0;
foreach( $digit[$i] as $key =>$value) { 
    $newDigitsArray['numbers']= [$i => $value];
    $i++;
}
\Log::info($newDigitsArray);
```

**Method 2:**

```
$newDigitsArray=[];
for($i=0;$i<count($digit);){
    $newDigitsArray[$i]=$digit[$i];
    $i++;
}
 \Log::info($newDigitsArray);
```

Comment: You are searching for [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: @User863 Can u please provide the code u meant?

Comment: @User863 I tried `$newDigitsArray=explode(",",$digit);`  , which gives me error `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given.`

Comment: Check whats in `$digit` variable by printing it with `var_dump($digit)`. You will get an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in php method `explode` to achieve this easily:

```php
> $digits = ['numbers' => '1,2,3']
= [
    "numbers" => "1,2,3",
  ]

> $digits['numbers'] = explode(',', $digits['numbers'])
= [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
  ]

> $digits
= [
    "numbers" => [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
    ],
  ]

>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use explode() to make this work,

```
$digits = ['numbers' => '1,2,3'];
$digits['numbers'] = explode(',', $digits['numbers']);
print_r($digits);
```

Output :

```
'numbers' => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
  ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
$digit = array();
$digit['numbers'] = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    
foreach($digit['numbers'] as $k => $v){
    $num[] = $v;
}
    
$neo_digit['numbers'] = $num;
    
echo '<pre>'.print_r($neo_digit, true).'</pre>';
```